# data.table matrix multiplication - cartesian product

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2

So I got to thinking about the data.table column-focused approach, and I thought it would be interesting if I didn't acast in order to do matrix multiplication, but rather just did the whole thing column-wise and see how data.table stacked up against %*%.

But for a real comparison, you have to do it right.

I came up with (as far as I can tell) the most straightforward approach:

```
# Make some 'matrices'
dt <- data.table(expand.grid(x = 1:1000, y = 1:1000))
dt2 = data.table(expand.grid(x = 1:1000, y = 1:1000))

# Generate some data
set.seed(531)
dt[, z := sample(1:0,1000000,replace = TRUE)]
dt2[, z := sample(1:0,1000000,replace = TRUE)]

setkey(dt,'y')
setkey(dt2, 'x')

dtcartprod <- dt[dt2, allow.cartesian=TRUE]
dtresult = dtcartprod[,.(z = sum(z*i.z)),by = c('x','i.y')]
```

This gives the correct result, but is so much slower than `acast` + `%*%` 
it's not even funny. (at least a factor of 20)

Clearly I should be doing this differently:

Should I be doing a join at all? or be smarter about my join? Is there a better way? I heard you can aggregate as you join, but I'm unclear how to do it, since I need to name variables that are created during the aggregation process.

EDIT: acast version:
`result <- melt(acast(dt, x ~ y, value.var = 'z') %*% acast(dt2, x ~ y, value.var = 'z'))`